# Try-catch until success - execution loop for generic methods or delegates

Tags: c#, generics, methods, delegates, try-catch

I want my code to keep trying a method until no exception is thrown, however, unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920657/repeating-a-function-in-c-sharp-until-it-no-longer-throws-an-exception), I would like it to be written as a generic method capable of running any input delegate/method. Here is what I've had in mind, but I am not sure how to pass the arguments or generic methods through it:

```
public void tryLoop(Delegate anyMethod, T[] arguments) {
    while (true) {                              
        // Could be replaced by timer timeout
        try {
            anyMethod(arguments);
            break;
        }
        catch {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait 2 seconds
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**: For the academics of it, I would also be curious to know if it's possible to return the result as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can settle for using closures, you won't need to have to pass parameters to this method all (or have multiple overloads). The result can be returned using a `Func`.

```
  public T tryLoop<T>(Func<T> anyMethod)
  {
     while (true)
     {
        try
        {
           return anyMethod();
        }
        catch
        {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // *
        }
     }
     return default(T);
  }


  void SomeMethod(int param)
  {
     var someLocal = "Hi";
     var anotherLocal = 0;
     var result = tryLoop(() =>
     {
        Console.WriteLine(someLocal);
        return param + anotherLocal;
     });
     Console.Write(result);
  }
```

To be honest, I wouldn't set an infinite retry, however - at best, if certain types of `retryable` error were returned, such as a database deadlock, or a timeout calling an erratic web service, then possibly 3 or 4 retries might be in order. Exceptions such `DivideByZero` or `FileNotFound` aren't likely to go away by running them indefinitely :-)

*** especially with deadlocks, sleeping for a [random period](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2056850/314291) is recommended, just in case other threads are also simultaneously deadlocking on exactly the same data - you don't want the same deadlock recurrence happening in 2000ms :-).

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is by using an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and remove the `arguments` parameter:

```
public void tryLoop(Action anyMethod) {
    while ( true ) {
        // Could be replaced by timer timeout
        try {
            anyMethod();
            break;
        }
        catch {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait 2 seconds
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you ultimate freedom in how to use it:

```
tryLoop(() => string.Reverse("abc"));
```

or like this:

```
String s1 = "A";
String s2 = "b";

tryLoop(() => string.Concat(s1, s2));
```

As you can see in the second example, you can directly take the arguments from the context of the `tryLoop` method being called. You can invoke anything there.

The good thing for this approach is that you will not have to use `Invoke` or `DynamicInvoke` as with a `Delegate` instead of `Action`, because these introduce a performance penalty.

If you need the result, you can re-write the above with a [`Func<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Action`, like this:

```
public T tryLoop<T>(Func<T> anyMethod) {
    while ( true ) {
        // Could be replaced by timer timeout
        try {
            return anyMethod();
        }
        catch {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait 2 seconds
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var reversed = tryLoop(() => string.Reverse("abc"));

String s1 = "A";
String s2 = "b";

var concatenated = tryLoop(() => string.Concat(s1, s2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this suit your needs. If not then please comment. Also not sure how it will be performance wise.

Also the `DynamicInvoke` method has an `object` return type. This you can use to return the result of the delegate. You can change the return type of method from `void` to `object`.

```
public void tryLoop<T>(Delegate anyMethod, T[] arguments)
{
    while (true)
    {                              // Could be replaced by timer timeout
        try
        {
            anyMethod.DynamicInvoke(arguments);
            break;
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait 2 seconds
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps